# If I install SQL Server CE 4.0, will apps targeting 3.5 continue to work?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

If I install SQL Server CE 4.0, will this have any effect on projects that use SQL Server CE 3.5? I just want to make sure 3.5 won't get written over or become unusable.

**Some context for this question:** I currently have a couple projects in the works that use LinqToSql (SqlMetal) and SQL Server CE 3.5. I want to make sure these projects will continue to work while I download and experiment with all the "new stuff"--Visual Studio 2010 SP1 beta, .NET 4.0 Update beta, Entity Framework 4 Code First CTP5, and SQL Server CE 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 can all be installed side-by-side, but SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not support SqlMetal, you must use Entity Framework instead.

Comment: Funny enough, 4.0 uninstalled my 3.5... Had to uninstall 4.0, then reinstall 3.5...

Comment: SQL Server Compact 3.5 and 4.0 installations are not related in any way.